# Why is my GPU overheating?

Tags: gpu, overheating

My computer’s GPU is overheating and here are some of the stats: It gets up to 60°C when playing on a game and the fans go up to 5k+ RPM.

Fan configuration:

- **Top:** 2 Blowing Out
- **Back:** 1 Blowing Out
- **Side:** 2 Blowing In
- **Front:** 2 Blowing In

**PCPartPicker List:** [PC Part Picker](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/CrLg7P)

**Build Images:** [Images](http://postimg.org/gallery/2ewnzoqtc/)

Comment: 60°C is not overheating - especially when playing games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your graphics card has an interesting feature;
this may explain this heat levels you're seeing:**

The Asus GeForce GTX 970 4GB STRIX Video Card you have in your linked cart does not turn on it's fan until the graphics card reaches a certain temperature (I would guess that's around 60 degrees C). This is on the manufacturer website and in lots of reviews as a cool new type of thing, so one imagines it's new to you if you just built a new rig... although the card has been out for a little while now.

Anyway, *that* is what would be causing this heat to get higher than you might expect during some types of use which you would expect not to create high temperatures. Thus you may believe your card is overheating (I would comment to clarify, but don't yet have rep). But yes 60 degrees celcius should not be a cause for worry:
 [here is a link to a review of this card lauding it for not peaking ~65°C compared to other cards that hit ~79°C](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/6789/asus-geforce-gtx-970-4gb-strix-oc-video-card-review/index15.html)... and I personally would not recommend messing with the manufacturer's settings without a darned good reason to doubt their engineering. Although I wonder if this might just shift load to system fans, doing little to prevent noise overall.

**In fairness to your question, however:**

This would be due to higher temperatures during load. Some basic thoughts for you (hopefully not too obvious) looking at the pictures... obviously the bottom side intake is (as it's supposed to be) low relative to the system internals (heat rises)... but if the tower is low to the ground this might impact airflow create a problem intaking dust/detritus from nearby carpet and floor. *Unless you have your tower on the absolute edge of the desk or raised off the floor you may find that raising it is helpful.*

You may also be trapping heat however by putting the tower too near the wall or that desk of yours which seems pretty solid and flush with the wall. Obstructing the escape of hot air from the top/back would allow for the heat to feed back into the area and make everything chug a little harder to keep things cool. *So altering the set up to allow for some gap or fanning air with an external fan out of that system may allow everything inside the computer to "chill out" substantially.*

(This may not cause the GPU to drop below 60 during any kind of use if it's not designed to clock on until a certain temp is reached, but ought to let the fan maintain the same temperature without clocking so high, and protect you from reaching higher heat under high load.

I know some of this might be obvious and there are good reasons to not want an external fan (look, noise)... but imho *from a practical standpoint there are cheap easy-to-hide little high velocity fans that could do the trick of making sure the heat gets out of a feedback loop by your desk, and sparing your fancy system (even the fan) over-use by utilizing an easily replaceable $9 high velocity 6 in fan from an office supply store is well worth it*. Albeit inelegant.

Comment: Do you know how I can activate said feature?

Comment: Sorry i was editing for format when you accepted! I hope the new answer is as good. It looks like the feature should be automatic, triggered by a temperature floor. If you would like to change that would imagine it could be tweaked, but as mentioned, I think you want to save your system internals undue work if that's within the operating range, and if you're seeing heat issues that actually cause major issues, perhaps consider other cooling, as well as some really simple suggestions I made in amending my original post

Comment: That;s getting more common. Your GPU should come with some software that would let you manage stuff like that. That said, fans kicking off, fast and loud during high load is normal

Comment: What about throttling the GPU fan speed, cause it is really loud when it does start up... My other fans should keep it cooler so I think throttling it would be nice, do you know how?

Comment: You mean just at start up? It should max itself out in my experience [reference also](http://tomshardware.com/answers/id-2438322/gpu-fan-max-startup.html) during startup to test... if it's running at full power during normal behavior I would wonder what's going on and reconsider: 1) the possibility that the main fans are failing to clear hot air and intaking it back in 2) that the GPU is overworked due to some process or 3) that something fritzed in like the cmos or bios settings that needs tweeking. They ought not to be chugging hard under normal use.

Comment: Also you have more fans blowing air in than fans blowing air in than out, which contributes to my assessment that you might be sucking hot air back in. Also just generally, I think you want more fans pointed out than in, because the vacuum will passively suck air in. So maybe your fans are running louder just b/c they're not quite optimally configured and have to work harder as a result?

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't consider it as overheating. According to TweakTown's benchmark tests your graphics card under full load could even hit up to 83°C.

See [here](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/6789/asus-geforce-gtx-970-4gb-strix-oc-video-card-review/index15.html)

If you'd like to have your graphics card even *lower* for overclocking and such, I'd consider having a liquid-cooled system.

Or if you don't mind the noise, manually turn the fans to max in MSI Afterburner.

TL;DR : +90°C is uncomfortably hot and in the long run (of a year) may cause permanent damage.

Comment: Is there a way to turn down the GPU fan so it doesnt get so loud?

Comment: Buy a different model of fan. There are surely some fans that make less noise. Or, like Raymond said, go for liquid cooling.

Comment: A different model of fan for my GPU?